# The meaning of "on" in "don't hit snooze on"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

What is the meaning of "on" in "[don't hit snooze on](https://milled.com/beach-bunny-swimwear/dont-hit-snooze-on-35-separates-7GGGoGp1m_SxArCf)"? "Hit snooze" means to press a button on an alarm clock that stops and resets the alarm for a short time later to allow for more rest. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your quote tries to make "snoose on" a phrase. Instead, parse "on" with the next phrase: "on the floor", "on the picture", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typical use would be "hit snooze on the alarm clock"—the "on" refers to the location of the snooze button.

Searching the web for "hit snooze on" reveals colloquial/creative usages like

> Don't Hit “Snooze” on Your Aspirations

> Don't hit snooze on this deal.

> Don't Hit Snooze on These 7 Delicious Brunch Dishes

It appears the idiom "Don't hit snooze on ____" is telling the listener not to ignore, dismiss, miss out on, or give up on some valuable opportunity/goal. The "aspirations" one could refer to *postponement*, because hitting snooze on an alarm clock postpones when the alarm will go off.

Answer (score 7):

When you hit an alarm clock snooze button,  you get to ignore the alarm and sleep a few more minutes.

> DON'T HIT SNOOZE ON $35 SEPARATES

The link shows a headline for a swimwear advertisement.

It asks us not to ignore the advert and "hit the button", and hence miss out on the $35 swimwear deal.

*on* takes the following meaning.

> on preposition (TO)

> A2
> to or towards:
> The attack on the village lasted all night.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on)

Comment: Thank you all very much for your detailed explanations! Now I understand what it means.